# how to write my script links related to particular component in angular

Tags: angular

how to write my script links related to particular component in angular this is my html code looks like i want to convert this into angular component i i used this script links in index.html it is diplaying in every page i want to restrict this script link to one particular component plz help thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_2e1eb"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/KRAKEN-XRPUSD/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">XRPUSD chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget(
    {
    "autosize": true,
    "symbol": "KRAKEN:XRPUSD",
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "Dark",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "enable_publishing": false,
    "hide_top_toolbar": true,
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "save_image": false,
    "container_id": "tradingview_2e1eb"
  }
    );
    </script>
  </div>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert to an Angular component? And exactly which script links do you want to put there?

Comment: Components are generally imported into NgModule, not linked via script tag in index file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I think you might want to have the script linked to only one component rather than globally? 
If so, you can call a particular js file like this in the component.

component.ts

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        $.getScript('./assets/js/script.js');
      }
```